# Hermitian Matrix n x n

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, matrices

Sea M an Hermitian matrix that satisfies the condition :

$$M^5 + M^3 + M = I $$

with I the identity matrix n x n.

How can i prove that $M = I$. Please help...

Comment: FALSE. For example$\displaystyle{\left(\begin{array}{rr}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{array}\right)^{2} = \left(\begin{array}{rr}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. The polynomial $x^5 + x^3 + x - 1$ has a real root $\lambda,$ so $\lambda I$ is a hermitian matrix satisfying the equation.

Comment: It may be that the intended problem was to be $M = aI$ for some scalar $a$. It is easy enough to show it is false in that if $M = I$, then, $M^5+M^3+M = I+I+I = 3I \neq I$.

Comment: $\large\lambda \approx 0.64$.